# C++ file won't open

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to open a file, but can't get it to work. The file is definitely there, in the same directory. I have tried unhiding extensions (it's definitely called test.txt and not test.txt.txt for example), and also tried using the full path. The file is not open anywhere. Any ideas?

```
string mostCommon(string fileName)
{
    string common = "default";
    ifstream inFile;
    //inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    inFile.open("test.txt");
    if (!inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "file opened ok" << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();
    return common;
}
```

Comment: I think you have to specify the open mode like this `inFile.open("test.txt", ifstream::in);`

Comment: @Johny the mode is implicitely specified as a default parameter, so it is not necessary, unless you wish to mix `std::ios_base::in` with other modifiers.

Comment: @SirDarius if you're using an `ifstream` the `in` flag is passed to the `basic_filebuf` regardless of what you provide to the constructor or `open`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify `inFile.open("test.txt")` it will try to open `"test.txt"` in the current working directory. Check to make certain that is actually where the file is. If you use absolute or relative pathing, make sure that you use `'/'` or `'\\'` as the path separator.

Here is an example that works when a file exists:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

bool process_file(string fileName)
{
    ifstream inFile(fileName.c_str());
    if (!inFile)
        return false;

    //! Do whatever...

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    //! be sure to use / or \\ for directory separators.
    bool opened = process_file("g:/test.dat");
    assert(opened);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the file was in the same place as my source file, it worked when I moved it into the same place as the make file. Not sure what I did wrong when specifying the full path, but anyway, it works now.

Comment: It's because your computer, when it executes your program, has absolutely no idea where this one source file came from. None at all. It doesn't even know where your makefile is: it just so happens that you're executing your program from that directory. _That_ is the current working directory that is used.

Answer (score 0):

Common problem might be specifying wrong path, CMakeLists.txt uses cmake-build-debug as its directory, so if your file is one level outside it, you just use`process_file("../test.dat");` this helped me.